# The "GetMinimumOSVersion" task was not given a value for the required parameter "SdkVersion"

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, command-line, msbuild, xamarin.iot

I am trying to run msbuild command line, but, I am getting in the last step of it, the error below (it is in portuguese, but is the same error in the title.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(227,3): erro
r MSB4044: A tarefa "GetMinimumOSVersion" não recebeu um valor para o parâmetro obrigatório "SdkVersion". [E:\2-PROJETO
S\_ALGORIX\Projetos\ACCORD\SOLUTION\AppAlgorix\AppAlgorix.iOS\AppAlgorix.iOS.csproj]
```

My msbuild command is:

```
msbuild AppAlgorix.sln /p:Configuration=AppStore;Platform=iPhone /p:CFBundleVersion=1 /p:CFBundleShortVersionString=2.3.1 /p:ServerAddress={mac ip address} /p:ServerUser={mac user} /p:ServerPassword={mac pwd} /p:BuildIpa=true /p:IpaPackageDir="E:\8-IPAS\ACCORD" /t:Clean;Build /p:ArchiveOnBuild=false /p:IsAppDistribution=false /p:CodesignKey="{App ID identifier}" /p:CodesignProvision="{App Provisioning Profile}"
```

All the {} data are confidential, so I cropped them.

This command was working one day, but I don´t know when, but after some VS 2019 update, the command, stops working.

I have found some articles about it, but I can´t find a way to resolve this problem.

Onw of those articles is this:

https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/xamarin/xamarin-macios/10109/729614745

My VS 2019 is updated in version 16.8.4.

[image]

I have here, about 40 apps to build and get the ipa. I was running a dosbat to resolve it, and get those ipas, more quickly. Not having this msbuild command line working, will take me to a big problem, cause I almost every week have some updates in my apps, and build one by one, will not be a great idea.

And one more thing is.. I can build inside VS 2019, without any problem. The problem happens only via msbuild command line.

Answer (score 1):

I used the post [Visual Studio update (16.8.1) lead to CI build failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64876303/visual-studio-update-16-8-1-lead-to-ci-build-failures) to resolve the error.

> "This has reared it's head again in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8.3.
> Looks like they've moved the problem to: \MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Messaging.targets I was able to get
> my builds running again by removing the _SayGoodbye dependency on line
> 52 for the _DisconnectAfterClean target."

Although I have resolved the error, now I cant generate the ios.ipa package. Now, I get only the file projectName.iOS.exe, instead of projectName.iOS.ipa.

I dont know if this workaround is the final solution for this bug, yet.

Comment: Since you have a workaround, I suggest you could [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/):)

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this by **running the build *twice in-a-row***. *(continue on error - **ignore the failed first build**)*

The first time always fails with the error in the question title, but it must somehow sets things up so that the second build has what it needs to succeed. The IPA is generated, etc.

IMPORTANT: DO **NOT** CLEAN BETWEEN THE TWO BUILDS

---

*I know this solution is a hack workaround, but I prefer it to manually making changes to the .targets files as I have seen suggested elsewhere (those suggestions did not work in our case anyway). Making changes like that without knowing the internals of the build process intimately could result in unintended side-effects.*

*NOTE: As this solution involves an expected failed partial first build, it does add to the build time, but it was only about a minute or two longer per build, and at least it works reliably.*

---

Hope this is helpful to someone!